# Java Actionlistener & getSource()

Tags: java, applet, awt

I'm trying to make an applet that will count how many times you have clicked a button, but it seems ActionListener isn't working properly. This code looks like it would work, but for some reason when I click the button in the applet, nothing is printed in the console or updated on the interface as it should.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Button Clicker;
    Button Upgrade;
    int currentClicks = 0;

    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(600,400);

        Button Clicker = new Button("Click");
        add(Clicker);
        Clicker.addActionListener(this);

        Button Upgrade = new Button("Autoclick Upgrade");
        add(Upgrade);
        Upgrade.addActionListener(this);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Test",300,50);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(currentClicks), 300, 100);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        String sString = ae.getActionCommand();
        if (sString.equals(Clicker))
        {
            System.out.println("Clicker was pressed");
            currentClicks++;
            System.out.println("Total Clicks: "+currentClicks);
            repaint();
        }
        else if (sString.equals(Upgrade))
        {
            System.out.println("Upgrade was pressed");
            if (currentClicks >= 25)
            {
                System.out.println("Upgrade was successfully purchased!");
                currentClicks = currentClicks - 25;
                repaint();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Upgrade was not successfully purchased!");
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing a _String_ object with a _Button_ object : _sString.equals(Upgrade)_

Comment: @Berger I have also tried ae.getSource() == Clicker & ae.getSource() = Upgrade, but that didn't work. How should I compare do this with a button?

Comment: `ae,getSource() == Clicker` does not work since you never initialize the field `Clicker`! Instead of assigning the button to the field you create a new local variable `Clicker`

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was just making this in my spare time as a test. I didn't exactly know any other methods of making an application that would run as an applet would. But thanks for letting me know about Swing! That would make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an action command to the Button :

```
Button Clicker = new Button("Click");
Clicker.setActionCommand("Click");
```

Then use that to determine what was clicked :

```
if (sString.equals("Click"))
```

**OR**

Compare the source button :

```
if(ae.getSource() == Clicker)
```